How can I traverse nested data (STRUCTs) in a DuckDB / SQL data dictionary?
In DuckDB, how can I traverse a nested structure (STRUCT), using either INFORMATION_SCHEMA or the duckdb_* schema functions?  I would also like to recognize an array type.  It would be nice if the solution were portable to Postgresql.
For example, the table
CREATE TABLE t(x BIGINT, y STRUCT(a BIGINT, b TEXT), z TEXT[]);

would generate a data struture that looks like this.
x  BIGINT
y  STRUCT
       y.a BIGINT
       y.b TEXT
z  ARRAY-TEXT

Context: writing some schema tracking tools.

Postgres does not have a Struct type so it would not be portable.

describe t is a starting point:
D CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t(x BIGINT, y STRUCT(a BIGINT, b TEXT), z TEXT[]);

D select column_name, column_type from (describe t);

┌─────────────┬─────────────────────────────┐
│ column_name │         column_type         │
│   varchar   │           varchar           │
├─────────────┼─────────────────────────────┤
│ x           │ BIGINT                      │
│ y           │ STRUCT(a BIGINT, b VARCHAR) │
│ z           │ VARCHAR[]                   │
└─────────────┴─────────────────────────────┘

One way to traverse a struct programmatically is by casting it to JSON.
Consider for example:
D insert into t values (1, {'a': 1, 'b': 'x'}, ['ab']);

D select list_transform(json_keys(j), x -> (x, j ->> x))
  from (select y::JSON as j from t);

┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ list_transform(json_keys(j), (x -> main."row"(x, (j ->> x)))) │
│                  struct(varchar, varchar)[]                   │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ [(a, 1), (b, x)]                                              │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


Thanks!  This is good for the data, and I'm going to try to adapt it traversing the data dictionary.
